# VS 2010 C++ phantom compile errors

Tags: visual-c++

**problem:** when attempting to build completed code VS 2010 returns with compile errors. when "errors" are checked in text environment after a few seconds VS 2010 recognizes that "errors" were in fact not errors at all with no external input. when build is attempted again the entire chain of events restarts.

**theories:** when i attempt to build VS 2010 it appears to "forget" many of the classes and structs that i have defined. many of the errors are required ';' in between a class or struct declaration and the variable name that it is attached to and the red squiggle that indicates an error appears under the struct / class definition.

*Example:* myStruct myNamedStruct; //in this case "myStruct" would show a red line underneath for a few seconds when viewed after each build attempt but then VS would decide it is fine after a few seconds.

**Trouble Shooting:** i have hit the "clean solution" button within the build tab and it consistently returns "Clean: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped" which seams like a positive response to me. i have tried restarting VS, hiding the .suo file (to make intellisense behave), systematically opening each program file forcing VS to properly run it's error diagnostic on each, along with tinkering with turning off and on some of the code environment settings within the tools -> options window.

**The rest:** i am not naive i am fairly certain my code does have errors within it, but these odd fake errors make it impossible to find and test the real errors. any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be actual *build* errors, but rather that the MSVC IDE seems to forget its internal symbols database. I don't know details about it, but perhaps the database is being rebuilt as well when you build, and therefore you get the red underlines while the database it being refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

after significant trouble shooting and research i have come to the conclusion that i was declaring my structs incorrectly (i was not using typedef). i still don't understand why the compiler was only saying they were bad when i tried to build and was ok with these errors the rest of the time.

edit: well after more tinkering the problem still persists. typedef solved the issue for my structs, but my classes are still popping the same "errors".

edit2: after more troubleshooting it was discovered that i had header files indirectly calling themselves through other header files. i guess in effect i was creating endless loops on build. i am still not sure why VS found these errors acceptable in the coding environment but producing errors at build.